# How to convert an object which can be array or single object to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like below

```
const foo = (x : Array<string> | string) {
   ...
}
```

Now I want to treat x always as an array, I have done this

```
const y = Array.isArray(x) ? x : [x];
```

I know I can have another function to do this, looking for some built-in javascript function.

(this is simplified version I am doing this multiple times try to DRY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[].concat()` or wrap the item with an array, and then flatten it:

```js
const fn1 = x => [].concat(x)

console.log(fn1({ a: 1 }))
console.log(fn1([{ a: 1 }]))

const fn2 = x => [x].flat()

console.log(fn2({ b: 2 }))
console.log(fn2([{ b: 2 }]))
```

If the function only has a single parameter, you can use rest params, and flatten the array of arguments:

```js
const fn = (...x) => x.flat()

console.log(fn({ a: 1 }))
console.log(fn([{ a: 1 }]))
```

Comment: Thanks Ori, the first solution works, for the second one, when spreading object then flat you will get the object props not an array with single object

Comment: I'm not spreading the an object, I'm collection all params to an array - see [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: I see thanks, you are using rest operator